# Rename and move file with Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I have a Python script that compares existing file names in a folder to a reference table and then determines if it needs to be renamed or not.

As it loops through each filename:

```
'oldname' = the current file name

'newname' = what it needs to be renamed to
```

I want rename the file and move it to a new folder "..\renamedfiles"

Can I do the rename and the move at the same time as it iterates through the loop?

Comment: Show us your loop code - your attempts to solve it.

Comment: Renaming and moving a file are the same thing.

Comment: Use [`os.rename`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename) and [`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget or, just use `shutil.move` as it does the correct thing anw.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`os.rename` (and `os.replace`) won't work if the source and target locations are on different partitions/drives/devices. If that's the case, you need to [use `shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), which will use atomic renaming if possible, and fallback to copy-then-delete if the destination is not on the same file system. It's perfectly happy to both move and rename in the same operation; the operation is the same regardless.

Comment: As per the docs, shutil.move only copies if the src & dest are on different file systems.

Comment: @norman_h: Umm... That's paraphrasing what my answer says? It atomic renames when possible, and falls back to copy-then-delete when they're not on the same file system.

Answer (score 48):

Yes you can do this. In Python you can use the `move` function in [shutil](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) library to achieve this.

Let's say on Linux, you have a file in `/home/user/Downloads` folder named "test.txt" and you want to move it to `/home/user/Documents` and also change the name to "useful_name.txt". You can do both things in the same line of code:

```
import shutil

shutil.move('/home/user/Downloads/test.txt', '/home/user/Documents/useful_name.txt')
```

In your case you can do this:

```
import shutil

shutil.move('oldname', 'renamedfiles/newname')
```

Answer (score 3):

To do both of the operations, you can use the `os.rename(src, dest)` function.

You should have the wanted directory to save the file in, and the new file name. You can do this for every file you run across in your loop.

**For example:**

```
# In Windows
dest_dir = "tmp\\2"
new_name = "bar.txt"
current_file_name = "tmp\\1\\foo.txt"
os.rename(current_file_name, os.path.join(dest_dir, new_name))
```

The `rename` function allows you to change the name of the file and it's folder at the same time.

To prevent any errors in renaming and moving of the file, use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3.4, working with paths is done easily with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib). Moving/renaming a file is done with [`rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename) or [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace) (will unconditionally do the replace). So combining with the [`parent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parent) attribute and the [concat operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators), you can do:

```py
from pathlib import Path

source = Path("path/to/file/oldname")

target = source.replace(source.parent / "renames" / "newname")
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Python file in your desired directory and write something like that :

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if(filename ...):
        newFilename = ...
        os.rename(filename, newFilename)
```